# Обработка onlick Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не создает обработчик onClick для объекта html формы.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="lib.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="drag_and_drop">
</body>
</html>
```

И код файла lib.js:

```
$('body').click(
    function()
        {
            alert('Вы нажали');
        }
            );
```

Много чего пробовал, на разных сайтах пишут что у них всё работает, у меня - нет. Может кто-то поймет в чем дело ?

P.S хочу создать подключаемую библиотеку для перетаскивания объектов по форме:)

```
$('#drag_and_drop').bind('click', function() {alert();});
```

не работает, а

```
$(document).bind('click', function() {alert();});
```

работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

хм, я уверен, что на body нельзя повесить обработчик нажатия.., попробуйте на другой тег повесить, например на div:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="lib.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="drag_and_drop">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function(){
     alert('Вы нажали');
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.

Comment: пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

На body можно повесить обработку событий так же, как на любой другой DOM элемент.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){alert()})
```

Просто нужно это делать после того, как DOM загрузилось на сайте. А для этого нужно внести подключение скрипта lib.js в конец body.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click', function(){
            alert('1');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="height: 400px;">

</body>
</html>
```

Можно вешать на body